# What Human Has Yellow Eyes?

Tags: star-trek

Data, Lore, and B4 all have yellow eyes and white metal exoskeletons. Why did Noonien Soong give them yellow eyes instead of blue or something natural? The Androids were supposed to be as human looking as possible but I don't see many people with yellow eyes. Wouldn't they have had a solution for their eye color and exoskeleton to appear more human in the future? In the TOS episode I Mudd, the Androids had a human exoskeleton color and normal eyes and that is earlier than TNG. Brent Spiner told a story of him asking Gene Roddenberry why did he have to have a different skin color but the answer he gave didn't really suffice.

Comment: Data doesn't have a white metal exoskeleton.  He has an endoskeleton and an outer covering that looks like skin.    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exoskeleton